# How to get path of root directory?

Tags: powershell, parent-child, root

I have a powershell file called main.ps1 and it is in a project file structured as such:

`APP > Tools > main.ps1`

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to getting the path of the App directory. I'm using the following function:

```
$myFile = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

function Root {
$parentPath = Split-Path -parent $myFile
$root = Split-Path -parent $parentPath
$base = Split-Path -parent $root
return $root, $base
}

$Root, $Base = Root
```

When the script is run MyInvocation saves the path of main.ps1 to the $myFile variable. Knowing this folder is always 2 folders deep in the App directory I use the `-parent` twice in a row and that gives me the path of the App folder.

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast [`[IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) from there you can get the parent directory of the file by calling the [`Directory` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directory?view=net-6.0#system-io-fileinfo-directory) and lastly, this will return a [`IO.DirectoryInfo` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) hence you can use the [`Parent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-parent):

```bash
([IO.FileInfo] $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Directory.Parent.FullName
```

There is also a more direct way of getting this information, using the [automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psscriptroot):

```
Split-Path $PSScriptRoot
```

If you want to emulate what your function is doing for `$base` and `$root` you can do:

```bash
$root = ([IO.DirectoryInfo] $PSScriptRoot).Parent
$base = $root.Parent
$root.FullName
$base.FullName
```

Comment: Santiago constantly coming in with the knowledge. You are appreciated. Not at my PC to test it now but I am going to accept the answer knowing full well you've once again got me on the right path. Thank you.

Comment: @IamJakoby thank you for the kind words, it's my pleasure to help ;)